# Parsing structured and semi-structured text with hundreds of tags with Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I will be processing batches of 10,000-50,000 records with roughly 200-400 characters in each record.  I expect the number of search terms I could have would be no more than 1500 (all related to local businesses).

I want to create a function that compares the structured tags with a list of terms to tag the data.

These terms are based on business descriptions.  So, for example, a `[Jazz Bar]`, `[Nightclub]`, `[Sports Bar]`, or `[Wine Bar]` would all correspond to queries for `[Bar]`.

Usually this data has some kind of existing tag, so I can also create a strict hierarchy for the first pass and then do a second pass if there is no definitive existing tag.

What is the most performance sensitive way to implement this?  I could have a table with all the keywords and try to match them against each piece of data.  This is straightforward in the case where I am matching the existing tag, less straightforward when processing free text.

I'm using Heroku/Postgresql

Comment: Where do you want the query/work to happen? In PostgreSQL or in your Ruby code? Is this a one-time task, or a regular job? And, what do you want to do when you identify the tags? Count the hits? Replace them with something else?

Comment: This is a daily / weekly job caching certain data and meta-data.  We have a tag-based query mechanism, so we'll attach a tag to the records we cache and keep a running total of the tagged items.  There are 8 top level tags and each of those has 2-8 leaf tags. thanks!

Comment: Not sure how fitting this is to your case, but have a look into Redis and Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty safe bet to use the [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) search engine and the [ThinkingSphinx](http://pat.github.com/ts/en/) Ruby gem. Yes, there is some configuration overhead, but I am yet to find a scenario where Sphinx has failed me. :-)

If you have 30-60 minutes to tinker with setting this up, give it a try. I have been using Sphinx to search in a DB table with 600,000+ records with complex queries (3 separate search criterias + 2 separate field groupings / sortings) and I was getting results in 0.625 secs, which is not bad at all and I am sure is lot better than anything you could accomplish yourself with a pure Ruby code.